Finding Hunspell supporting .aff and .dic file for chinese, kyrgyz, syiac and french(monaco)
Hello I am working on a spell checker and need .aff and .dic files for some languages which shall be Hunspell compatible. I am looking for .dic and .aff for Chinese Simplified, Chinese Singapore and Chinese traditional. Also I am looking for dictinaries of Syrian, Kyrgyz, french(switzerland) etc
I am unable to find any dictionary.
